# Is there a range expression that can be used to refer to the last N elements of a slice?

Tags: rust

I have a slice of unknown length and I would like to try get a slice to the last N elements of that slice. The only way I can think of doing this is as follows (e.g., for 4 elements):

```rust
if let [.., a, b, c, d] = my_slice {
    //...
}
```

This feels very cumbersome though. I would have thought that one of the [range expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/range-expr.html) would have provided this functionality, but none of them seem to do so... Is there another way of doing this? Ideally, I would be able to work with a slice and not the individual values a, b, c, d in my example above.

Comment: There is the slice method `pub fn last(&self) -> Option<&T>` which returns a single element. It seems that a slice method such as `pub fn lastn(&self, n: usize) -> Option<&[T]>` has been accidentally left out...

Answer (score 1):

I like your solution, but you could use [`get`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get). A simple version looks like this:

```
fn last4<T>(slc: &[T]) -> Option<&[T]> {
    slc.get(slc.len()-4..slc.len())
}
```

In practice, you'd need to check that `slc.len()` is at least 4.

See it in action: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2c9472aea45cf23b1f46b54de7132cd7.

Comment: Note that `len-4` panics when `len<4`.

Comment: It panics in debug builds, not in release builds.

Comment: `slc.len()-4..` is sufficient; you don't need to specify the end of the range.